# Output row with no duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

I am trying to output the most recent row but not show any duplicates. My table has a unique id (note_id) and issue_id that can be assigned to multiple (note_ids); this way every entry is unique but can be associated to a common issue.

Here's my code:

```
$issueSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT issue_id FROM notes WHERE assigned = '$loginID' ORDER BY note_id ASC";
    $issueQuery = mysql_query($issueSelect);
```

Then I have an output statement in a while loop:

```
while ($issueResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($issueQuery)){
$issueID = $issueResult['issue_id'];
$issue = $issueResult['issue'];
      if ($issue == "open" or $issue == "assigned"){
                echo"<td align='right'><a href=\"note_details.php?note_click=$issueID\">$issueID</td>";
```

}

For some reason though, I keep getting nothing... when I just put `SELECT *` it shows stuff , but it includes the duplicates (which I don't want).

Anything I am missing that may be why this isn't working?

Comment: Where in your query are you selecting the "issue" field? (hint: you're not, which is why nothing gets displayed because your conditional inside your loop always fails)

Comment: @Crontab where should I select the issue? Should that be inside the while loop with a separate query or adjust the original $issueSelect? & how?

Answer (score 1):

So, you're using a compound key of `note_id` and `issue_id`? You should try using the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT `issue_id`, `issue` FROM `notes` WHERE `assigned` = '$loginID' GROUP BY `note_id`, `issue_id` ORDER BY `note_id` ASC;
```

Also, `mysql_*` is now deprecated, and you shouldn't really be using it. Look up PDO and `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get anything because `$issue` is `null`. You may be able to use `group by issue_id` instead of `distinct`, but it's non-standard and may or may not work based on your installation.

If it doesn't work, you may want to use `select *` and then filter the duplicates in PHP.

Comment: how would you suggest if filter duplicates with PHP?

Comment: Keep an array, using the issue_id as keys. Then before outputting a row, check `if(!isset($arr[$issueID]))`

Answer (score 0):

had to actually select the issue field (among other fields that I wanted displayed... here's what I did:

```
$issueSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT issue_id, issue, reason, customer_id, order_id, return_id, author_id FROM notes WHERE assigned = '$loginID' ORDER BY note_id ASC";
    $issueQuery = mysql_query($issueSelect);
    while ($issueResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($issueQuery)){
$issueID = $issueResult['issue_id'];
        $issue = $issueResult['issue'];
        $assigned = $issueResult['assigned'];
        $openDate = $issueResult['date'];
        $closeDate = $issueResult['close_date'];
        $orderID = $issueResult['order_id'];
        $returnID = $issueResult['return_id'];
        $customerID = $issueResult['customer_id'];
        $authorID = $issueResult['author_id'];
        $reason = $issueResult['reason'];
}
```

Thanks for all your help guys... and I will look into POD & MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

Your original query was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT issue_id FROM notes WHERE assigned = '$loginID' ORDER BY note_id ASC
```

I think this produced multiple rows because of the ORDER BY clause.  You're implicitly extending the select-list with `note_id`, then ordering, then projecting away the `note_id`, but there are multiple notes for a single issue, so you've got multiple rows being returned for a single issue despite the DISTINCT (because DISTINCT is done before ORDER BY).